# Fetching YouTube videos very slow with HTTPS but ok without SSL

Tags: php, ssl, https, youtube-api

When I load/display my latest YouTube videos it is noticeable slower with http**s**. With SSL Chrome shows a TTFB at an average of 4,2 seconds. Without SSL it is mostly < 180 ms.

Do I have to use the official PHP API client? Is something wrong with my SSL implementation (installed on a managed server)?

```
$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$channel_id = 'yyyyyyyy';


$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId='. $channel_id .'&maxResults=10&order=date&key=' . $api_key);
$youtube = json_decode($json, true);


$videos = array();
foreach ($youtube['items'] as $video) {
    if ($video['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video') {
        $videos[$video['id']['videoId']]['id'] = $video['id']['videoId'];
        $videos[$video['id']['videoId']]['thumbnail'] = '<img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $video['id']['videoId'] . '/hqdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">';

        $json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=' . $video['id']['videoId'] . '&fields=items(id,snippet)&key=' . $api_key);
        $video_json = json_decode($json, true);
        $videos[$video['id']['videoId']]['title'] = $video_json['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
    }
}
```

Later on I just loop through the items. Currently 1 video. I tested, if the slowdown is because of the iFrame embed, but if I remove that part it is still slow. Only if I remove the PHP code it is fast as it should be.